How to Initialize Future<String>
I am using Flutter.
I defined variable like this:
late Future<String?> myvariable;

I get error message saying that myvariable should be initialized.
I cannot assign a value like 'abc' to myvariable b/c is future string.
How do I initialize Future string variable?
Thank You

Can't you just assign it null?

If you have a good default value for myvariable, you can use that with Future.value:
Future<String?> myvariable = Future.value("my default");


But at that stage, I recommend just getting rid of the Future altogether:
String myvariable = "my default";

And then use await when you want to reassign a different value to myvariable.

Also see:

Returning String as Future breaks FutureBuilder on /r/flutterhelp


You can try something like this:
late Future<String> test;
test = Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () => "test");

